# How to easily update a dataobject without the use of a function in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this

```
       <Checkbox 
         label="View"
         :initialState="data.something"
         @updateStatus="updateCheckbox" >
       </Checkbox>
```

data.something is a boolean. I want to change this boolean if the checkbox changes. The checkbox emits the new value (true/false). I know i can use a function to do that easily but i have a lot of checkboxes, so how do i know which data.something i have to update? Is the only option to write a function for all the checkboxes or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!

Somebody did give an answer but it wasn't entirely what I needed. But his answer was the missing piece!

```
@updateStatus="data.something = !data.something "
```

The problem was, I was too focused on getting the emitted value instead of listening to the event and then doing something!

Comment: great to hear, Arvoci! I had to removed it, to think about it a little bit more...

Answer (score 0):

Using the methods for this kind of work is the best way, and you don't need to care about which `data.something` you have to update. Because when you pass any object to the function, **it references those params in your function**. So when you modify that data inside the function, it will **update your particular** `data.something`.

Try to create a function and pass the object inside it, **it will only update that "data"**.

Here is an example:

**In event listen:**

```
@updateStatus="inverseSomething(data)"
```

**Method to update:**

```
inverseSomething(data) {
        data.something = !data.something
      }
```